# Foreign Key in Berkeley DB

Tags: java, database, foreign-keys, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I have two entities:

The first one is:

```
public class WordEntity {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String content;

    private int wordId;
}
```

The second one is:

```
public class LexiconEntity {
    @SecondaryKey(relate = Relationship.ONE_TO_ONE, relatedEntity = WordEntity.class)// it does not work
    private int wordId;

    private int numDocs;
}
```

I want to `wordId` of the `LexiconEntity` be the foreign key of that of `WordEntity`. How can I do this?

Comment: shouldn't LexiconEntity also have a PrimaryKey?
Does the compiler yield any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but... First it looks like the wordId would be a more natural PK for the WordEntity. The LexiconEntity should also define a PrimaryKey. The WordEntity should define the SecondaryKey which refers to the LexiconEntity or "Specifies the entity to which this entity is related".

```
public class WordEntity {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int wordId;
    private String content;
    @SecondaryKey(relate = Relationship.ONE_TO_ONE, relatedEntity = LexiconEntity.class)
    private int lexId;
}

public class LexiconEntity {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int lexId;
    private int numDocs;
}
```

Therefore data would be:

```
LexiconEntity:
lexId
-----
100
101
102

WordEntity:        
wordId  lexId
------  -----
1       100
2       101
3       102
```

Since the relationship is one_to_one, the secondary key is unique to the object defining it. So in this case, lexId is unique in the WordEntity, so you cannot have:

```
WordEntity:        
wordId  lexId
------  -----
1       100
2       101
3       100 -- Exception on insert since it is a dup
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/GettingStartedGuide/dplindexcreate.html#dplsecondaryidxdecl
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/java/com/sleepycat/persist/model/SecondaryKey.html#relatedEntity()